# What kind of algorithm should I look for in order to recognize the blueprint of a building?

Tags: python, image-recognition

I have a project in which I should analyze the layout of a building in order to navigate inside it, and I was thinking about taking the blueprint of the building (or maybe an edited version of the blueprint, which should be modified in some way I am still thinking of), transforming it in some kind of object and then elaborate it.

Basically, I was thinking about doing something similar to OCR but limited (and I guess using limited sounds pretty silly to most of you, but still bear with me) to recognition of, for example, walls and doors. My idea was transforming the whole image into a matrix of points - I guess, a lower resolution version of the source - and then elaborating over the matrix the route from point A to point B.

This is the idea, but I guess that I'm actually looking at a problem way more complex than it looks to me, moreover I don't really know whether this is the best (read: easiest) way to proceed.

In short, my question is:
Is this framework feasible? Are there any libraries for, say, Python, with similar functions? Is the recognition doable by working in someway with a graphic design software (e.g. Photoshop)?

Comment: Maybe Sobel edge detection algorithm can help you to process the blueprint image.

Comment: What is your source? image or vector? If it is image (jpg/png/tiff) then you probably should start with a vectorization algorithm (see comment by @YuriMalheiros). Things are probably easier in vector format...